# In GWT MVP, how to save state in the URL, without navigating to another place?

Tags: gwt

I have a simple page, with a small form and a table for results. When the user clicks the "Search" button, I'd like the form contents to saved in the URL, so that the search is "bookmarkable". So what I would really like to do is to update the URL (place) without triggering the whole MVP machinery (my current activity can handle the new place without restarting).

How can I do that? I tried to mess with the History class directly, but then the back button behave strangely. Looking at SO I found out about the CachingActivityMapper, but I'm not sure whether that's the "right" approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CachingActivityMapper (or anything similar) is the *right* approach.

The thing is, if an ActivityMapper returns the same instance (really the same, not even an instance that compares `equals()`) as the current activity, then the ActivityManager does nothing (particularly, doesn't restart the activity).

Note however that it really does *nothing*, so your activity will have to listen to `PlaceChangeEvent`s ti be notified of the change (or your ActivityMapper could "notify" it before returning it to the ActivityManager; this is basically the approach taken by the Expenses sample, where activities are singletons, and the ActivityMappers calls `setPlace` on them).