# VIA the GWT places API how do you change the URL/PLACE/Place-Token without reloading the page?

Tags: gwt, gwt-places

We have a giant table of orders in a GWT page.  As users click on an order the bottom half of the page loads the details for that order.

When OnSelect of an entry in the table I could fire a place change event and change the place token from #OrdersPlace: to #OrdersPlace:123 where 123 is the order number.  The problem is that would require the entire table to reload as well.

Is there a way to just change the URL from #OrdersPlace: to #OrdersPlace:123 so on a browser refresh I can get back to where I was by reading the Place Token without starting from scratch by reloading the entire activity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In GWT MVP, how to save state in the URL, without navigating to another place?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482833/in-gwt-mvp-how-to-save-state-in-the-url-without-navigating-to-another-place)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gin you can make the view a singleton and just have it hold onto the existing data. Think of it similar to removing the table from the DOM and then just re-adding it.

There are equivalent ways of doing the same thing without using Gin too.